# Change ActiveItem whilst maintaining view state in Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a number of `ViewModels` that derive from the `Screen` object and I have derived my `ShellViewModel` from `Conductor<T>.Collection.OneActive`.

If I make a new `ActivateItem` request such as:

```
ActivateItem(new AViewModel());
```

The associated view is made active in my `ContentControl`, great.  If I then make another request:

```
ActivateItem(new BViewModel());
```

`AViewModel` is `deactivated` and `BViewModel` is made `active`, however, `AViewModel` is also closed.

To prevent the `ViewModel` from being closed, I moved to passing already instantiated instances into the `ActivateItem` method.  This **appears** to work as I desire.

My question is how do I keep track of `ViewModel`s that have already been created, I don't always want to create new instances.  The reason for this being I want to maintain the state of a `View\ViewModel` even if a user navigates to another `View` only to return.  I could either maintain them in a `Collection` in my `ShellViewModel` or make use of the `Items` `Collection` in the `Conductor`.

Which of these is correct, if either, or is there a better solution to my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a separate collection for this, because sooner or later you will come into synchronization problems *(not related to threading)*, or in other words you will need to keep your custom collection and the `Items` collection in synch with each other, add more that this will cause more confusion.

I would definitely use the `Items` collection because it is there for this purpose.

Comment: The synchronisation issue is a very good point, one which had eluded me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't necessarily say if it's the correct approach, but when I've been in a similar situation using `ViewModel` derived from `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive`, I've taken to using your first suggestion, and have maintained a collection of `ViewModels` on the `Conductor` `ViewModel`.

I found it quite handy conceptually, as it seemed to be in line with the composition ideas present when building other `ViewModels`. I've found myself occasionally preloading certain `ViewModels` on the assumption that they may want to be activated later. I've also used such a list to keep track of closed/removed `ViewModels` after they had been remove from the `Items` collection (although that was for something quite specific, I'm not sure if that's good practice).

For most simple cases, you could do it with the `Items` collection and probably not encounter any problems at all.